# Create new instance of extended element

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 3.4

I have an element:

```
App.Components.ComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
    constructor: function (config) {

        config = Ext.apply({
            triggerAction: 'all',
            mode: 'local',
            editable: true,
            lastQuery: '',
            forceSelection: true
        }, config);

        App.Components.ComboBox.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }    //other methods ommited
});
Ext.reg('appcombo', App.Components.ComboBox);
```

I would like to create this element dynamically and load it's store.

I know I can create ComboBox with:

```
var newCB = Ext.form.ComboBox(config);
```

But how to create new element of type appcombo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var myCustomComboBox = new App.Components.ComboBox({... your config ...});
```

or with xtype:

```
{
    xtype: 'appcombo',
    ...
    ...
}
```